# Lock cache with Apache Ignite.NET thin client

Tags: c#, .net, ignite

Currently we use Apache Ignite.NET thin client to cache different sets of data. When data request has came we check if data is already stored is the cache and, if not, request data from database and put it into the cache.

I want to prevent several database requests if two data requests has came at the same time.
Is there any way to manually lock cache before the first database request started? Thus second data request could wait until first request is completed.

I cannot solve the task isung .NET concurrency primitives cause cache could be used by multiple client instances (load-balancing).

I've already found ICache.Lock(TK key) method, but it seems that it locks only specified rows in cache and is supported only for in self-hosted mode, not for Ignite.NET this client.

Small piece of code that illustrates the issue:

```
var key = "cache_key"; 

using (var ignite = Ignition.StartClient(new Core.Client.IgniteClientConfiguration { Host = "127.0.0.1" }))
{
    var cacheNames = ignite.GetCacheNames();
    if (cacheNames.Contains(key))
    {
        return ignite.GetCache<int, Employee>(key).AsCacheQueryable();
    }
    else
    {
        var data = RequestDataFromDatabase();

        var cache = ignite.CreateCache<int, Employee>(new CacheClientConfiguration(
            EmployeeCacheName, new QueryEntity(typeof(int), typeof(Employee))));

        cache.PutAll(data);

        return cache.AsCacheQueryable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexandr has provided a good and simple solution if you just need to initialize the cache once.

If you need more complex synchronization logic, atomic cache operations (`PutIfAbsent`, `Replace`) can often replace locks. For example, we could have a special cache to track the status of other caches:

```
        var statusCache = Client.GetOrCreateCache<string, string>("status");
        if (statusCache.PutIfAbsent("cache-name", "created"))
        {
            // Just created, add data
            ...
            //
            statusCache.Put("cache-name", "populated");
        }
        else
        {
            // Already exists, wait for data
            while (statusCache["cache-name"] != "populated")
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The thin client doesn't have the required API.

If you don't need to check for individual records and it's only required to know whether the cache is available, you might just call CreateCache multiple times. It should throw an exception saying that the cache with a particular name already has started for further invocations.

```
try {
    var cache = ignite.CreateCache<int, Employee>(new CacheClientConfiguration(
            EmployeeCacheName, new QueryEntity(typeof(int), typeof(Employee))));
    // Cache created by this call => add data here
} catch (IgniteClientException e)  when (e.Message.Contains("already started")) {
    // Return existing cache, don't add data
}
```